# Como utillizar dos valor de una funcion en otra funcion

Tags: c++, funciones

El problema dice: Calcule la media de la edad de sus compañeros. La edad es generada aleatoriamente
de entre 18 y 23 años dentro de la función, que realiza la suma y devuelve la suma; la
media es calculada en otra función que recibe la suma y devuelve el resultado.

Todo lo he hecho bien, el problema esta en la segunda función en donde tengo que sacar el promedio solo puedo usar el valor retornado de la función primera que es la suma de las edades. El promedio  da si yo le dejo un valor asignado de mi, pero en realidad va el valor dependiendo cuanto sea el valor que ingrese el usuario. Me explico a continuacion...

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <conio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <time.h>

float generadorEstudiantes (float alum);

float media (float prom );

int main (){

float prom, alum;

printf ( "\nEL PROMEDIO DE LA EDADES ES DE: %.2f", media (prom));

}

float generadorEstudiantes (float alum){
int i, can;
int rango, n, cd;
srand (time (NULL));
rango = 24-18;

printf ("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos:\t");
scanf ("%d", &can );

for (i=0; i<can; i++){
n = rand () % rango + 18;
alum += n;
cd = cd + 1; 
printf ("\nEstudiante %i: %d", i+1, n);
}
printf ("\n\nLA SUMA DE LA EDADES ES: %.2f", alum);
return alum; 
}
```

En esta función yo le asigne el  valor de **5** para poder sacar el promedio de la suma de las edades, solo lo puse para ver si imprimia bien el promedio. Ahora bien, claro está, que ese no sería el promedio correcto ya que el valor que va donde esta 5 es el **contador** que esta en la función **generadorEstudiantes (float alum)**, la variable **cd** que cuenta, cuanta edades se van a ejecutar, esa variable es la que va reemplazar 5, entonces ese es el problema, como hago para pasar esa variable si solo en esa función retorna solo un valor que es **alum** = es la suma de las edades. Ya intente hacer que la función retorne 2 valores que seria la suma y el contador pero como hago para que se divida y poder sacar el promedio en la segunda función.

```
float media (float prom ){
float alum, n; 
n = generadorEstudiantes (alum);
prom = n / 5;    

return prom; 
}
```

Comment: C++ no es lo mismo que C. Supongo que tendrás que hacerlo con variables globales o punteros (o si estás en C++ también podrías usar referencias).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apuntes iniciales:

- **tabula el código**. Un código sin tabular es tremendamente complicado de leer y los errores se empezarán a reproducir como si fuesen lindos conejitos. Estás avisado.
- Desde hace más 30 años no es necesario declarar todas la variables al inicio de la función. Esta práctica no es para nada aconsejable pues se alarga innecesariamente la vida de las variables y ahí es cuando podemos acabar reutilizando una variable ... este suele ser el origen de numerosos errores al programar. Intenta que la vida de las variables sea la mínima imprescindible.

Vamos con tu código.

Tienes un problema en las dos funciones que has definido, y es que ambas reciben como parámetro una variable cuyo valor no usan en ningún momento:

```
float media (float prom ){
//                 ~~~~ <<--- recibes prom como parametro
    float alum, n; 
    n = generadorEstudiantes (alum);
    prom = n / 5; // <<--- pero sobreescribes su valor
    
    return prom; 

}
```

Si la función recibe un parámetro es porque necesita un valor que debe ser proporcionado desde fuera para que la función pueda trabajar correctamente. Si la función no necesita dicho valor, entonces no debería recibir ningún parámetro.

Hablando ahora de la función `generadorEstudiantes`:

- No deberías invocar `srand` en una función que hace más cosas ... el motivo es que cada vez que llamas a `srand` modificas la semilla del generador de números. Si esta función se invoca dos o más veces en el mismo segundo (es la precisión de `time(NULL)`) entonces obtendrás varias veces la misma secuencia de números aleatorios
- `alum` no debería ser un `float` sino un entero. En esta función no tienes ninguna necesidad de recurrir al uso de decimales. De hecho debería tener un nombre más adecuado, como `suma_edades`. Un código facil de leer te dara menos problemas.

  int generadorEstudiantes ()
  {
  int rango = 24 - 18;

  ```
    int numero_alumnos;
    printf ("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos:\t");
    scanf ("%d", &numero_alumnos);

    int suma_edades = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numero_alumnos; i++){
        int edad = (rand () % rango) + 18;
        suma_edades += edad;
        printf ("\nEstudiante %i: %d", i+1, n);
    }
    printf ("\n\nLA SUMA DE LA EDADES ES: %d", suma_edades);
    return suma_edades;
  ```

  }

Adelantándonos un poco al siguiente problema, esta función no debería pedir el número de alumnos, ya que este dato va a ser necesario para poder calcular la media. Este es un dato que o bien podemos pedir en una función independiente o bien directamente en el `main`:

```
int NumeroAlumnos()
{
    int numero_alumnos;
    printf ("Ingrese la cantidad de alumnos:\t");
    scanf ("%d", &numero_alumnos);

    return numero_alumnos;
}
```

Ahora sí tendría sentido que `numeroAlumnos` reciba un parámetro. Fíjate que ahora la función tiene un parámetro y, a cambio, pierde el código que inicializaba la variable.

```
int generadorEstudiantes (int numero_alumnos)
{
    int rango = 24 - 18;
    
    int suma_edades = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numero_alumnos; i++){
        int edad = (rand () % rango) + 18;
        suma_edades += edad;
        printf ("\nEstudiante %i: %d", i+1, n);
    }
    return suma_edades; 
}
```

Ahora vamos a por la función `media`. Esta función no debería llamar a `generadorEstudiantes` directamente sino que lo suyo sería pasarle la suma y el número de valores para que pueda calcular el promedio:

```
float media(int numero_alumnos, int suma_edades)
{
    return numero_alumnos / (float)suma_edades;
}
```

Y ya solo nos quedaría enlazar todas estas funciones en el `main`:

```
int main()
{
    srand (time (NULL));

    int numero_alumnos = NumeroAlumnos();

    int suma_edades = generadorEstudiantes (numero_alumnos);
    printf ("\n\nLA SUMA DE LA EDADES ES: %d", suma_edades);

    float promedio = media(numero_alumnos, suma_edades);

    printf ("\n\nLA SUMA DE LA EDADES ES: %.2f", promedio);
}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias señor Eferion por las correciones y los consejos sobre los errores que he cometido en los códigos, estoy apenas empezando en programación, le agradezco, ya pude comprende un poco mejor sobre el tema de las funciones.